# expected specific-qualifier-list before 'function' and expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'function'

Tags: c, objective-c, xcode

I am programming in Objective-C but I would like to write a c function to increase the performance.  I have written the code below this post but the compile keeps coming back with the following error:

> error: expected specific-qualifier-list before 'bool'
>
> error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'addToBoolArray'

structs.h:

```
typedef struct boolArray{
bool *array;
int count;
} boolArray;

bool addToBoolArray(boolArray *bArray, bool newBool)
```

structs.c:

```
#import "structs.h"

bool addToBoolArray(boolArray *bArray, bool newBool)
{
if(bArray->count > 0){
    bArray->array = realloc(bArray->array,(bArray->count+1)*sizeof(bool));
else{
    bArray->array = (bool *)malloc(sizeof(bool));
}

if(bArray->array == NULL)
    return false;

bArray->array[bArray->count] = newBool;
bArray->count++;

return true;
}
```

I've found many forum threads about this error but none of them seem to address my issue.  Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no `bool` type in C89 or Objective-C.

For plain C89, typically `int` is used.

For C99, you can do:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

For Objective-C, it seems that there's a typedef for `BOOL`, and constants `TRUE` and `FALSE`, is NSObject.h.

Comment: In C99 there's the predefined type `_Bool` which works with no need to #include any headers.

Comment: Yes, of course it's really just `typedef _Bool bool`. In practice, though, I haven't ever seen anyone use `_Bool` directly, just as noone uses `_Complex` directly. The sole reason why it was done that way is to avoid introducing new keywords that could clash with some that were already widely used.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `BOOL` from `<objc.h>`. If you want to use (the C99 type) `bool`, include `<stdbool.h>`.

You are also missing a `;` after the declaration of `addToBoolArray` in your header file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to increase performance, you might want to use a [bit vector](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bit_vector.html) instead of an array of `bool`s…